# add printf to variable and get unsuspected result

Tags: c++

why I get the result n as the length of first string

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
 int n = printf("jjj");
    printf("%d",n); // jjj3
    return 0;
}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: What do the reference pages say under "return value"?? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: You don't get jjj3.

The first printf prints "jjj"

Comment: The second prints "3".  Then output shows jjj3

Comment: kiamoz, Posted code is not C.   Perhaps you want a C++ answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) returns the number of characaters that have been written, as stated in its manual ([`printf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html#RETURN_VALUE))

> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).

Hence the `3` in your output. The `jjj` printed string comes from the first `printf` call.

```c
int n = printf("jjj"); // prints "jjj"
printf("%d", n); // prints "3" (assuming previous printf did not fail)
```

Comment: thank you I just want  to know  2


printf returns the number of characaters

Answer (score 1):

printf also  return the number of char